# Animating a Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am working on a project where I need to visualise a sorting algorithm.

I looked around and found Javascript and CSS3 have some good animation functions for blink and swap to visualize this.

But my professor prefers Java so I was wondering if there is a hybrid way of using Java and Javascript where I call these Javascript animation functions inside Java.

I also want a simple way to accomplish the task of animating a sort algorithm as a web application.

Comment: you could always get some Hungarians to dance it out for you http://www.neatorama.com/2011/04/11/sorting-algorithms-explained-with-a-hungarian-folk-dance/

Comment: In reverse Polish notation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but will probably take a couple of days to implement for a professional software developer.

While you can run JavaScript code in Java, that doesn't give you a full browser (no DOM, no windows, no rendering of CSS and HTML).

So you would need to embed a web browser in Java, first. This is possible but all solutions need JNI or at least hardware specific shared libraries. If you feel up to the task, go for it. I suggest to try SWT. [You can find demo code here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/); the widget is called `Browser`.

If you don't want to spend a month or more on this homework, [start with this code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJPanelasacanvas.htm).

If you want to know whether you got it right: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the complexity involved! I am planning to just do it in JS.